# Help with rails ordering by foreign column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-order-by

- A Student has_many grades
- Grade is a polymorphic Class...
- An Exam is Gradeable and it belongs to a period
- An Activity is Gradeable and it belongs to a period
- A Game is Gradeable and it belongs to a period

I need to be able to get the grades for a student ordered by the period_id

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :grades, :order => "period_id"

end
```

obviously doesnt work but I cant figure out the right way to achieve this.

Please Help.

Comment: Can you please provide your models of Grade, Exam and Period? I think those will help to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like :

```
student.grades.order('period_id ASC') # or DESC
```

Also, bear in mind that looking for order in _id values is never a good idea. It would be much better to order by something else, like the timestamp.

Comment: "period_id" is not a attribute of Grade

Comment: ... no comments... you are simply not helpful

Comment: why, have you tried and did not work ? You never gave any feedback. If you want to order students by period_id, that is how it is done. You do something like student.order('period_id ASC').grades. Does this not help ?

Comment: The point is... an exam has period_id, and activity has period_id, a game has period_id..... a grade DOES NOT HAVE period_id....

Comment: you seriously make no sense man. You want to sort grades by period_id, but they don't have a period_id field ? What the..

Comment: the grade doesnt have the period_id because it is a polymorphic class!... grade.gradeable.period.id is the only way to get to the period_id corresponding to that grade.....